# Why isn't this variable undefined?

Tags: javascript, variables, if-statement

I'm extremely new to JavaScript so my apologies if the answer is obvious but I am testing out a script and unfortunately I cannot figure out what is happening.

```
let taxableIncome = 1000;
let Income;
let y;

if(taxableIncome == 18201 || taxableIncome >18201 && taxableIncome 
<37001); {
 y = taxableIncome - 18200
Income = y - 0.19 * y + 18200
}

console.log(Income);
```

The console is logging the number as 4268 where it should be undefined because taxableIncome is only 1000 and therefore does not meet the if requirements so the code inside should not be run.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: You should enclose parentheses around every pair of boolean expressions you want to compare when it seems to be giving you an unexpected result. Also, the end `)` after an `if` should not have a semicolon. Did you mean `if(taxableIncome == 18201 || (taxableIncome > 18201 && taxableIncome < 37001)) {` ? (or you might just use `>=`)

Comment: Did you try using a debugger to see what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

You should not have `;` after `if`. By specifying `;` , you are basically terminating the statement and making the code block (`{...}`) independent of the condition:

```js
let taxableIncome = 1000;
let Income;
let y;
if(taxableIncome == 18201 || (taxableIncome >18201 && taxableIncome 
<37001)) {
  y = taxableIncome - 18200
  Income = y - 0.19 * y + 18200
}

console.log(Income);
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the semicolon after your if condition:

`if(taxableIncome == 18201 || taxableIncome >18201 && taxableIncome <37001) {
...
}`

The semicolon 'ends' the if, and the curly braces are just another code block that will run regardless of the if condition.

Answer (score 0):

This should give you the expected results. You need to remove the `;` after the if statement.

```js
let taxableIncome = 1000;
let Income = null;
let y = null;

if (taxableIncome >= 18201 && taxableIncome < 37001){
    y = taxableIncome - 18200
    Income = y - 0.19 * y + 18200
}

console.log(Income);
```